# PyGame draws a blank window until quit

Tags: python, macos, pygame

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    color = (100,100,200)
    screen.fill(color)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I think this should create a 200x200 window and fill it with the RGB color (100,100,200). Instead of this, it creates a blank 200x200 window. When I control-c to quit, the window flashes the correct color for one or two frames then closes. Why is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame window not responding after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165492/pygame-window-not-responding-after-a-few-seconds)

Comment: @skrx It is the same issue, but I would suggest you keep this question up as the symptoms of the mistake can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to siliconwolf on the PyGame Discord server, here is the answer:

If you don't process PyGame events with `pygame.event.get()`, then you must use `pygame.event.pump()` at the beginning of the loop or the window will freeze. However, `pygame.event.get()` is strongly preferred because you may have issues closing the window otherwise.