# How can I make a moving rectangle by pressing 1 key?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make code to move a rectangle by pressing a key. In my code I made a while loop to keep drawing a rectangle that moves to the right in steps of 10 pixels but my progrem only shows the drawing execution of the end of the while loop.

Does anybody knows what I am doing wrong or how to fix it.

See my code below:

```
x=10
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, (0, 10, 10,10))



   while True:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == QUIT:
          pygame.quit()
          sys.exit()
      elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
          if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
              while x<=380:
                  pygame.time.wait(100)
                  x = x + 20
                  print(x)
                  DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)
                  pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, (x, 10, 10,10))



pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Pygame window not responding after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165492/pygame-window-not-responding-after-a-few-seconds).
Note, the display is updated when [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update), but to make the timing and display update proper work, you've to handle the events between the updates of the display by either [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) or [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump). Avoid loops which do some drawing inside the game loop. Use the game loop to perform the animations.

You don't need the inner while loop at all. You've a game loop. Add a state `move` and initialize it by `False`.

```py
move = False
```

When the key is pressed then change the state to `True`:

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    move = True
```

If `move` is stated and as long `x <= 380` increment `x`:

```py
while True:

    # [...]

    if move and x <= 380:
        x += 20
```

The game loop should look like this:

```py
x = 0
move = False
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                move = True

    if move and x <= 380:
        x += 20

    pygame.time.wait(100)
                  
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, (x, 10, 10,10))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do do `pygame.display.update()` every time you draw. Move that line to be called inside your while loop after `pygame.draw.rect`