# Pygame window immediately opens and closes

Tags: python, pygame

Originally after I did some searching here, I found a question with the exact same problem I had:
[Pygame window not responding after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165492/pygame-window-not-responding-after-a-few-seconds) . I reviewed all the answers and tried them, but none of them worked. I tried using for loops to loop through every single event;

```
run = True
while run:
for event in pygame.event.get():
   if event == pygame.QUIT()
       run = False
```

But the window still closed. I also tried:

```
run = True
while run:
    event = pygame.event.get()
    if event == pygame.QUIT():
        run = False
```

Which had the same results as the one above.
Can anyone help?
Edit: I use PyCharm and MacOS Catalina.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pygame.QUIT` is a constante, but `pygame.QUIT()` is a call statement. Remove the braces. Anyway, the condition won't work, because you have to compare the `type` attribute of the event to the event type constant (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)). Furthermore the `:` is missing at the end of the `if`-statement.

<s>`if event == pygame.QUIT()`</s>

```py
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
```

Furthermore the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) is not correct:

```py
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
```